# Lightning Web Component and NavigationMixin

Tags: lightning-web-components, navigation, lightningnavigation

In my LWC I'd like to open a standard "new record" dialog with predefined values. I know I can use:

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
    type: 'standard__objectPage',
    attributes: {
        objectApiName: 'Account',
        actionName: 'new'
    },
});
```

But how can I specify values for the fields on that dialog?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, You can not set predefined values for it. I have raised the idea on Idea Exchange, you can upvote it.

You can use force:createRecord as a workaround. Here is the idea description :-

> Aura component use the force:createRecordevent to display an
>   prepopulated new record page. As we are migrating to Lightning web
>   component, we do not have that ability.

Reference:- [Allow setting pre-default values in record form by navigation service in LWC](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CYGkQAO)

Also, I have raised issue for it on Github, and as reply i get to know it is being planed for upcoming release.

[https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/issues/66](http://set%20default%20value%20while%20navigate%20to%20new%20record%20#66)

Comment: It's available now since Spring 20  (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/254498/lightning-web-components-navigate-to-the-new-object-page-passing-in-specific) (added the comment to make it more clear)